# How to fit 2 containers and input box side by side

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to frontend - HTML, CSS and bootstrap. I basically want to do a comparison page, where users can enter search terms and the table below will display the information pulled from a database. Currently, when I tried to place the 2 tables and input containers side by side, they overlap and are way too close to each other.

So my question is - what is the best way to style these containers so that they look like the wireframe below?

Thank you!

This is what my page looks now:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide an example of how your page looks like now. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I've updated the question - thanks!

Comment: Please even provide code that you have tried...

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap row and column approach
as it will make them responsive too
Example

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6"> Your First Box </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6"> Your Second Box </div>
                </div>
```

What this will do is it will create a row in which two columns of 50% width will take place

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
}

.column {
    flex: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made an simple example of your case here with **Bootstrap** `row` and `col`. Hope it was to any help.

If you want to read more how the grid works in **Bootstrap**: [Boostrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/)

```css
.box {
border: 2px solid gray;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
margin: 30px;
border-radius: 25px;
}

.input-field{
margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
    <input class="col input-field"/>
    <input class="col input-field"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col box"></div>
    <div class="col box"></div>
    </div>



    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I create an example with bootstrap 5

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-start">
    <div style="width:500px" class="pt-3 px-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search">
      <div class="results rounded border mt-3">
        <div class="item d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border-bottom flex-column py-3">
          <span class="text-secondary">filter1</span>
          <h3 class="fw-bold">RESULT 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border-bottom flex-column py-3">
          <span class="text-secondary">filter1</span>
          <h3 class="fw-bold">RESULT 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column py-3">
          <span class="text-secondary">filter1</span>
          <h3 class="fw-bold">RESULT 1</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:500px" class="pt-3 px-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search">
      <div class="results rounded border mt-3">
        <div class="item d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border-bottom flex-column py-3">
          <span class="text-secondary">filter1</span>
          <h3 class="fw-bold">RESULT 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center border-bottom flex-column py-3">
          <span class="text-secondary">filter1</span>
          <h3 class="fw-bold">RESULT 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="item d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column py-3">
          <span class="text-secondary">filter1</span>
          <h3 class="fw-bold">RESULT 1</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```